# How to vary a second order function with respect to the metric tensor?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, riemannian-geometry, geometric-functional-analysis

Can anybody help me to prove this relation, how is it is valid ?

\begin{equation}
\frac{\delta}{\delta g^{\mu\nu}}\nabla_{\sigma}\Bigr(\alpha(x^{\beta})\,\frac{\nabla^{\sigma}{\phi(x^\beta)}}{\phi(x^\beta)}\Bigl)=\frac{1}{2}g_{\mu\nu}\nabla_{\sigma}\Bigr(\alpha(x^{\beta})\,\frac{\nabla^{\sigma}{\phi(x^\beta)}}{\phi(x^\beta)}\Bigl)
\end{equation}

Here $x^{\beta}$ is just space time coordinate.  $\alpha(x^{\beta})$ and  ${\phi(x^\beta)}$ are scalar functions and Einstein summation  convention is used. The term that I take variation with respect to metric tensor $g_{\mu\nu}$ is just a scalar function.

In addition, how can I find 
\begin{equation}
\frac{\delta}{\delta g^{\mu\nu}}(\Box{\phi})=?
\end{equation}
Also
\begin{equation}
\frac{\delta}{\delta g^{\mu\nu}}(\Box^n{\phi})=?
\end{equation}

Regarding the first question, I tried the following way,

\begin{equation}
\frac{\delta}{\delta g^{\mu\nu}}\nabla_{\sigma}\Bigr(\alpha(x^{\beta})\,\frac{\nabla^{\sigma}{\phi(x^\beta)}}{\phi(x^\beta)}\Bigl)=\frac{\delta}{\delta g^{\mu\nu}}\frac{1} {\sqrt{-g}}\partial_{\sigma}\Biggr({\sqrt{-g}}\alpha(x^{\beta})\,\frac{\partial^{\sigma}{\phi(x^\beta)}}{\phi(x^\beta)}\Biggl)\\ 
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\frac{\delta}{\delta g^{\mu\nu}}\nabla_{\sigma}\Bigr(\alpha(x^{\beta})\,\frac{\nabla^{\sigma}{\phi(x^\beta)}}{\phi(x^\beta)}\Bigl)=\frac{\delta}{\delta g^{\mu\nu}}\Bigr(\frac{1} {\sqrt{-g}}\Bigl)\partial_{\sigma}\Biggr({\sqrt{-g}}\alpha(x^{\beta})\,\frac{\partial^{\sigma}{\phi(x^\beta)}}{\phi(x^\beta)}\Biggl)+\Bigr(\frac{1} {\sqrt{-g}}\Bigl)\frac{\delta}{\delta g^{\mu\nu}}\partial_{\sigma}\Biggr({\sqrt{-g}}\alpha(x^{\beta})\,\frac{\partial^{\sigma}{\phi(x^\beta)}}{\phi(x^\beta)}\Biggl)\\ 
\end{equation}
Using the result
\begin{equation}
\frac{\delta}{\delta g^{\mu\nu}}\Bigr(\frac{1} {\sqrt{-g}}\Bigl)=(\frac{-1}{-g})\frac{-1}{2}{\sqrt{-g}}\, g_{\mu\nu}=\frac{1}{2}g_{\mu\nu}\frac{1}{\sqrt{-g}}
\end{equation}
I get
\begin{equation}
\frac{\delta}{\delta g^{\mu\nu}}\nabla_{\sigma}\Bigr(\alpha(x^{\beta})\,\frac{\nabla^{\sigma}{\phi(x^\beta)}}{\phi(x^\beta)}\Bigl)=\frac{1}{2} g_{\mu\nu}\frac{1} {\sqrt{-g}}\partial_{\sigma}\Biggr({\sqrt{-g}}\alpha(x^{\beta})\,\frac{\partial^{\sigma}{\phi(x^\beta)}}{\phi(x^\beta)}\Biggl)+\Bigr(\frac{1} {\sqrt{-g}}\Bigl)\frac{\delta}{\delta g^{\mu\nu}}\partial_{\sigma}\Biggr({\sqrt{-g}}\alpha(x^{\beta})\,\frac{\partial^{\sigma}{\phi(x^\beta)}}{\phi(x^\beta)}\Biggl)\\  
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\frac{\delta}{\delta g^{\mu\nu}}\nabla_{\sigma}\Bigr(\alpha(x^{\beta})\,\frac{\nabla^{\sigma}{\phi(x^\beta)}}{\phi(x^\beta)}\Bigl)=\frac{1}{2}g_{\mu\nu}\nabla_{\sigma}\Bigr(\alpha(x^{\beta})\,\frac{\nabla^{\sigma}{\phi(x^\beta)}}{\phi(x^\beta)}\Bigl)+\Bigr(\frac{1} {\sqrt{-g}}\Bigl)\frac{\delta}{\delta g^{\mu\nu}}\partial_{\sigma}\Biggr({\sqrt{-g}}\alpha(x^{\beta})\,\frac{\partial^{\sigma}{\phi(x^\beta)}}{\phi(x^\beta)}\Biggl)\\  
\end{equation}

My trouble is, I was not able to prove 
\begin{equation}
\Bigr(\frac{1} {\sqrt{-g}}\Bigl)\frac{\delta}{\delta g^{\mu\nu}}\partial_{\sigma}\Biggr({\sqrt{-g}}\alpha(x^{\beta})\,\frac{\partial^{\sigma}{\phi(x^\beta)}}{\phi(x^\beta)}\Biggl)=0\\
\end{equation}
The difficulties is, I don't know how to evaluate the variation of the derivative of the determinant of the metric tensor.

Comment: Are you sure the first eq is correct ? I think you missed $\sqrt{g}$ and thats the source of your problem. The factor $-1/2 g_{\mu\nu}$ comes from $\delta \sqrt{g}$

Comment: What is $\alpha$? Is a vector field? Is $\alpha(x^\beta)$ the componente of $\alpha$ relative to the index $\beta$? Is $\phi$ a scalar function? I assume so since you divide by it.

Comment: Looks to me like $\alpha,\phi$ are both scalar functions of position $x$.

Comment: I'm more concerned about the actual meaning of $\frac{\delta f}{\delta g^{mu \nu}}$ when the output of the "functional" $g \mapsto f$ is function-valued and depends on derivatives of $g$: can you give a definition of exactly what you mean? Is it just the "partial" derivative with respect to the zeroth derivative, i.e. to make $$\delta f = \frac{\delta f}{\delta g^{\mu \nu}}\delta g^{\mu \nu} + \frac{\delta f}{\delta (\partial_\sigma g^{\mu \nu})}\partial_\sigma (\delta g^{\mu \nu})$$ true?

Comment: $f$ is just a scalar function  with no dependence on $g^{\mu\nu}$. But $\Box$ operation makes it $g^{\mu\nu}$ dependent.

Comment: @Warlock of Firetop Mountain  $\alpha$ and $\phi$ are just scalar  functions. Here $x^\beta$ is just its space-time coordinate.

Comment: When I wrote $f$ I was referring to the whole quantity $\nabla_\sigma(\alpha \nabla^\sigma \phi / \phi).$ I'm still not clear on your definitions.

Comment: f is just a scalar function, but it contains $g_{\mu\nu}$ and derivatives of $g_{\mu\nu}$ which makes the problem difficult. Your varation $\delta{f}$ is correct

Comment: As you really need an answer it is better you include all details and notation to give more fancy explanation of what you need. for instance what does $x^\beta $ means. are you using Einstein summation? these couple of words could certainly help to solve your problem

Comment: $x^{\beta}$ is just space time coordinate. All functions are scalar here, I use Einstein convention of summation. The term that I take variation with respect to metric tensor $g_{\mu\nu}$ is just a scalar function.

Comment: @Anthony don't think of the functional as function-valued. Rather, think of it as a functional that evaluates a certain function at a given point $x$. Then the funcional derivative will contain delta functions and derivatives of delta functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for reading my post and for the comments.
I found a way to prove the last term vanishes. This was trivial.

I need to prove,
\begin{equation}
\Bigr(\frac{1} {\sqrt{-g}}\Bigl)\frac{\delta}{\delta g^{\mu\nu}}\partial_{\sigma}\Biggr({\sqrt{-g}}\alpha(x^{\beta})\,\frac{\partial^{\sigma}{\phi(x^\beta)}}{\phi(x^\beta)}\Biggl)=0\\
\end{equation}

This is the part of the action

\begin{equation}
A=\int{d^4x \sqrt{-g}\frac{1} {\sqrt{-g}}\frac{\delta}{\delta g^{\mu\nu}}\partial_{\sigma}\Biggr({\sqrt{-g}}\alpha(x^{\beta})\,\frac{\partial^{\sigma}{\phi(x^\beta)}}{\phi(x^\beta)}\Biggl)}=\int{d^4x \frac{\delta}{\delta g^{\mu\nu}}\partial_{\sigma}\Biggr({\sqrt{-g}}\alpha(x^{\beta})\,\frac{\partial^{\sigma}{\phi(x^\beta)}}{\phi(x^\beta)}\Biggl)}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
A=\int{d^4x \frac{\delta}{\delta g^{\mu\nu}}\partial_{\sigma}\Biggr({\sqrt{-g}}\alpha(x^{\beta})\,\frac{\partial^{\sigma}{\phi(x^\beta)}}{\phi(x^\beta)}\Biggl)}=\frac{\delta}{\delta g^{\mu\nu}}\int{d^4x \partial_{\sigma}\Biggr({\sqrt{-g}}\alpha(x^{\beta})\,\frac{\partial^{\sigma}{\phi(x^\beta)}}{\phi(x^\beta)}\Biggl)}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
A=\frac{\delta}{\delta g^{\mu\nu}}\int{d^4x \partial_{\sigma}\Biggr({\sqrt{-g}}\alpha(x^{\beta})\,\frac{\partial^{\sigma}{\phi(x^\beta)}}{\phi(x^\beta)}\Biggl)}=\frac{\delta}{\delta g^{\mu\nu}}\Biggr({\sqrt{-g}}\alpha(x^{\beta})\,\frac{\partial^{\sigma}{\phi(x^\beta)}}{\phi(x^\beta)}\Biggl)|_{on\,the\,boundary}=0
\end{equation}
This is true if the variation of the boundary is zero, then this surface term vanishes.